# SVG path position on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I have simple path like bellow. As I understand it should sticks to the top left corner of the canvas. But I'm having it rendered somewhere in the middle. And as result all paths I am rendering seem to be shifted from their original positions. Am I missing something very obvious? I'm using fabric.js for all canvas manipulations. Any clues are very appreciated.

`path1 = new fabric.Path('M 0 0 L 300 100 L 200 300 z');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [Fabric gotchas](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Fabric-gotchas) states:

> Left/Top values of all objects (including groups) correspond to an object's center, and are relative to top/left corner of a canvas. The center-based origin is default, but you can change it via originX/originY properties of an object.

That is not the problem. Because the path is not always centered properly either.

The problem is a bug in the positioning of the `path`s: [bug #1363](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1363).

That bug fix is done, but unfortunately that is not part of their latest release yet (1.4.11). So I think you have 2 options:

1. Upgrade your version of Fabric to the [latest in their master branch](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/tree/master/dist). (i.e. not released code: probably unstable)
2. Workaround it.

**And to workaround it**, you can set to zero either the **`left` and `top`** or the **`originX` and `originY`**.

For instance with:

```
var path1 = new fabric.Path('M -100 0 L 50 0 L 100 100 z');
path1.set({ left: 0, top: 0 });
```

Or:

```
var path1 = new fabric.Path('M -100 0 L 50 0 L 100 100 z', {originX: 0, originY: 0});
```

You can test that code in here: http://jsfiddle.net/protron/6qc5vsbj/3/

Comment: Thanks! That explains everything